# How to backup a recoverable Cognito user pool?

Tags: backup, amazon-cognito, disaster-recovery

Does anyone have recommendations or best practices on how to backup a recoverable Cognito user pool?

I'm using nodejs serverless to create a CloudFormation with all the assets, including the Cognito setup. I'm looking for a way to export or save a backup of the user pool data somewhere incase the stack ever needs redeployed from scratch.

I'd prefer to keep the assets tied together, but even if I take the Cognito setup out of the CloudFormation template, I'm still interesting in knowing if a backup to recover from is possible incase something else happens to the user pool (like a region going down).

If it matters, we aren't using Cognito in production yet; the team I'm on is trying to evaluate it now.  I'm aware of a couple nodejs packages, [cognito-backup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-backup) and [cognito-backup-restore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-backup-restore), but they both require everyone to reset their passwords if the backup actually needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to restore a Cognito user pool without requiring users to reset their passwords. I'd recommend telling Amazon that you find this unacceptable, and migrating to [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform) (which supports this) if possible.